# Why does my onclick property not run the function upon submit?

Tags: javascript

everyone. Bit of a JS noob. First question on here. I tried being more specific through the Stack Overflow submission guidelines but I'm not sure how to, as I'm not sure what's wrong with this. Tips to become a better asker are appreciated.

I'm building a simple JS todo list, trying not to use video tutorials. I just simply can't figure out what's wrong with this. On hitting the 'submit' button, nothing happens either in the console log or on the actual page. What am I doing wrong?

```js
let todoInput = document.getElementById("input");
let list = document.getElementById("submit");
let form = document.getElementById("form");

list.onclick = function addTodo(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // todo div
  const todoDiv = document.createElement('div');
  todoDiv.classList.add('todo');
  // todo LI
  const newTodo = document.createElement('li');
  newTodo.innerText = todoInput.value;
  newTodo.classList.add('todo-item');
  todoDiv.appendChild(newTodo);
  if (todoInput.value === "") {
    return null
  }
};
```

```html
<h1>TODO LIST</h1>
<form id="form" onload="false">
  <input id="input" type="text">
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because when you've created the `todoDiv` element, you are not appending it to your DOM at all. If you want to append it to the `#output` element, you can add the following line at the very end:

```
document.getElementById('output').appendChild(todoDiv);
```

NOTE: Your `li` elements must be appended to `<ul>` elements. You can just change `#output` to be a `<ul>` element and append your list items directly to it:

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
let todoInput = document.getElementById("input");
let list = document.getElementById("submit");
let form = document.getElementById("form");
let output = document.getElementById("output");

list.onclick = function addTodo(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // todo LI
  const newTodo = document.createElement('li');
  newTodo.innerText = todoInput.value;
  newTodo.classList.add('todo-item');
  output.appendChild(newTodo);
};
```

```html
<h1>TODO LIST</h1>
<form id="form" onload="false">
  <input id="input" type="text">
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<ul id="output" class="todo"></ul>
```